# How to pass logical parameters with the Quarto R package to the knitr chunk options via a parameterized Quarto document in R

Tags: r, quarto

I've provided a minimal reproducible example below. I'm currently trying to use the R quarto package to pass a logical parameter into the Quarto chunk options.

Below is the quarto document, where I created 2 parameters, `show_code`, and `show_plot`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
params:
  show_code: TRUE
  show_plot: TRUE
---

```{r, echo=params$show_code}
summary(cars)
```

```{r, include=params$show_plot}
plot(pressure)
```
````

This document would render properly via the render button in R studio.

However, when trying to render this document via the `quarto_render()` function from the R quarto package, this would fail.

```
library(quarto)

quarto::quarto_render(
  input = 'qmd_document.qmd',
  output_format = 'html',
  output_file = 'qmd_document_with_code.html',
  execute_params = list(show_plot = TRUE,
                        show_code = TRUE)
)
```

[image]

It appears that a character `yes` is passed instead of the logical `TRUE` or `FALSE` to both Chunk 1 and Chunk 2 in the console.

How do I properly pass the logical characters to a parameterized Quarto report chunk options via `quarto_render()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1 (Using chunk options in chunk header)

We can use logical statement in chunk option ([as we do in r-markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-variable.html)).

---

**parameterized_report.qmd**

````
---
title: "Using Parameters"
format: html
params:
  show_code: "yes"
  show_plot: "yes"
---

```{r, echo=(params$show_code == "yes")}
summary(cars)
```

```{r, include=(params$show_plot == "yes")}
plot(pressure)
```
````

---

Then from either r-console/rscript file, we call `quarto_render` using params `"yes"` or `"no"`,

```
quarto::quarto_render(
  input = 'parameterized_report.qmd',
  output_format = 'html',
  output_file = 'qmd_document_with_code.html',
  execute_params = list(show_plot = "yes",
                        show_code = "no")
)
```

---

[image: html output with only code output and plot]

---

### Option 2 (Using YAML syntax chunk option)

Note that, above we have used the chunk option in the chunk header which works fine with knitr engine, but quarto prefers comment-based yaml syntax (i.e. using `#|`). As per the [quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/tools/rstudio.html#knitr-engine)

> Note that if you prefer it is still possible to include chunk options on the first line (e.g. ```{r, echo = FALSE}). That said, we recommend using the comment-based syntax to make documents more portable and consistent across execution engines. Chunk options included this way use YAML syntax rather than R syntax for consistency with options provided in YAML front matter. You can still however use R code for option values by prefacing them with **`!expr`**

So following the quarto preferred way, we can use parameters like this,

---

**parameterized_report.qmd**

````
---
title: "Using Parameters"
format: html
params:
  show_code: "false"
  show_plot: "false"
---


```{r}
#| echo: !expr params$show_code

summary(cars)
```

```{r}
#| include: !expr params$show_plot

plot(pressure)
```
````

---

then use `quarto_render` with `"true"` or `"false"`

```
quarto::quarto_render(
  input = 'parameterized_report.qmd',
  output_format = 'html',
  output_file = 'qmd_document_with_code.html',
  execute_params = list(show_plot = "true",
                        show_code = "true")
)
```

Lastly, note two things,

- here we have used `"true"` or `"false"`, since `echo`, `include`, `eval` takes value `true`/`false` instead of `TRUE`/`FALSE` in this comment-based syntax.
- Additionally, Since `knitr 1.35`, knitr engine also supports this comment based syntax. See [News from knitr v1.35 to v1.37: Alternative Syntax for Chunk Options](https://yihui.org/en/2022/01/knitr-news/)

Comment: great! thank you so much! I've accepted this answer! I was confused why the logical parameter would not pass, and instead have to use a work around with characters

Comment: @MichaelLuu, I am not quite sure why `TRUE` gets translated to `yes` when used as parameter, maybe that's how render functions are written internally. That's why I like the comment-based syntax which is easier and consistent  with using `"true"` or `"false"`

Comment: thank you again for the thorough response and suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the R package **quarto**

Quarto follow YAML 1.2 spec with no support for `yes/no` and **yaml** R package used by **quarto** R package is following 1.1 spec with `yes/no` support for boolean.

```r
cat(yaml::as.yaml(list(show_plot = TRUE, show_code = TRUE)))
#> show_plot: yes
#> show_code: yes
```

This is theses issues

- https://github.com/vubiostat/r-yaml/issues/131
- https://github.com/vubiostat/r-yaml/issues/76

R package Quarto > 1.3 will have a fix for this.